# Can I use the word "ensure" to guarantee something negative to someone?

Tags: word-choice

Can I use the word "ensure" to say that something guarantees the negative effects to something/somebody, or is there any other suggestion?

For example:

> The design of our work ensures high-grade security  for both software
>   and hardware attackers.

In this sentence, the attacker does not benefit from our design but tampered with it.

I think I should use the ensure with other preposition such as against, but not sure.

Could you recommend another word instead of the ensure or correct preposition?

Comment: You probably mean: The design of our work ensures high-grade security 
***from***  both software and hardware attackers.

Comment: You can use provide, but in this sentence you're providing to the purchaser of the software to place a defence against attackers. You're not providing directly to the attackers.

Comment: I edited my question 
@Josh To me, the word "provide" sounds like giving something useful to someone. Is it available to use the "provide" to say give something  harmful/negatives to someone?

Comment: please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

> **Ensure** *verb*
>   1 Make certain that (something) will occur or be the case.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ensure)

The structure of your sentence is

- X ensures Y for Z.

That is, the statement claims that doing X makes certain that Y is certain for Z.

To "guarantee something negative", simply make Y negative.

- Positive case: X ensures high-grade security for Z. This means that by doing X, Z will have high-grade security.
- Negative case: X ensures **no** high-grade security for Z. This means that by doing X, Z will not have high-grade security.

If you want to say that Y applies positively, but to the detriment of Z, you can modify the part between Y and Z. Here are a couple of ways to do this:

- X ensures Y *against* Z.
- X ensures Y, *to the detriment of* Z.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I totally understand your point. However, it seems that many other answers say that I should use the against instead of the for. What do you think about that?

Comment: @JaeHyukLee You can do that as well - that's covered in the last part of my answer, penultimate bullet point.

Comment: I appreciate your kind answer. By the way what about the provide? Someone above this reply says I could use the provide instead of the ensure

Comment: @JaeHyukLee It depends. *Ensure* and *provide* are synonymous in this context, though *provide* has slightly more of the feel of a 'deliverable' itself, while *ensure* has slightly more of the feel of the *effect* of the 'deliverable'. Arguably, if you supply (say) bodyguards, you *provide* the guards and *ensure* security. If you *provide* security, you're the guard. But *security* can be a metonym for *guards*, so you can still say you *provide* security when you're actually providing *guards*. There's quite a bit of flexibility in the language.

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence implies that attackers will benefit from high-grade security therefore **ensures** doesn't work as you'd like it to in this case.

You need to say "The design of our work ensures high-grade security **defence against** both software and hardware attackers".

**Ensure** can be used to guarantee a negative outcome but, as with any such sentence, the outcome itself needs to be correct.

Comment: It seems that an object should follow the "against" not the someone. Is it correct? or can I put someone after the against?

Answer (score 0):

> "*The design of our work ensures high-grade security **for** both
>   software and hardware attackers.*"
>
> Because of the presence of the preposition '**for**' after 'security',
>   the meaning of the sentence has become like 'the design of our work
>   ensures the security of the attackers (on behalf of them).
>
> The preposition with **'security**' should be **'against'**:
>
> *"The system is designed to provide maximum **[security against](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=security&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=xqu_WKaQIpyS9QWe9quIDw#q=security%20meaning%20and%20definition&*)** toxic spills"*.
>
> "The banks must tighten **[security against](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/security)** fraud."

Comment: Did you mean to put the entire post in quotes? It is difficult to tell which text is your answer and which is a quote from someone else :)